# How to grant public visibility to all Contacts with private Accounts?

Tags: contact, accountcontactrelation, multiple-contacts

We want to activate `Contact to Multiple Accounts` but we have Accounts and Contacts visibility as private.

If we activate this functionallity an User can't view all Contacts to relate them to an Account. So we want to make all Contacts visible to all Users, but if we do this the User who can view the Contact also can view the Account.

We have thought many ideas:

- As Salesforce recommend, we have thought about creating a generic Account for each region, but we run into Data Skew (more than 10,000 of child records). We can create a Trigger to manage this with multiple  Accounts, but is a very bad implementation.
- Creating a sharing rule to give visibility of Contacts, but as I said, the user also view the Account.
- Creating Contacts without Account, but Salesforce make them as private and we have the same probem (Salesforce idea: [Contacts Without Accounts Idea - Ability to make them not 'Private'](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrOsAAK))

So the question is easy, How can I make all Contacts visible to create a relation if the Accounts are private?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep both contacts and accounts private
2. Create a custom component that will query contacts in system mode, and return this to the custom component in a String format (this will allow contacts to be returned regardless of sharing settings)
3. Let user select one of these "String contacts"
4. On submit, create an account contact relationship record in the backend (system mode) using the contact Id from the users selection